# Arduino menu coding problem by Keypad and 128*64 graphic LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, u8glib

I am trying to modify on the menu code to be able to use a keypad shield and arduino for scrolling between lines. after uploading and trying the code the following has happened:
1- I can not scroll more than 2 lines.
2- If I press D, I can scroll to another 2 lines.
What is the problem in this code?

```
include "String.h"
include"AccelStepper.h"
include "Keypad.h"
include "U8glib.h"
U8GLIB_ST7920_128X64_1X u8g(12, 11, 10, 13);

//Keypad setup

const byte ROWS = 4;

const byte COLS = 4;

char hexaKeys [ROWS][COLS] = {

{'1', '2', '3', 'A'}, {'4', '5', '6', 'B'}, {'7', '8', '9', 'C'}, {'*', '0', '#', 'D'} };

byte rowPins [ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};

byte colPins [COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad (makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

define KEY_NONE 0
define KEY_PREV 1
define KEY_NEXT 2
define KEY_SELECT 3
define KEY_BACK 4
uint8_t keycode1 = KEY_NONE;

uint8_t keycode2 = KEY_NONE;

uint8_t keycode = KEY_NONE;

void keymode(void){

keycode2 = keycode1;

char keypressed = customKeypad.getKey();

if (keypressed != NO_KEY){

switch (keypressed){

case 'A':

keycode1 = KEY_PREV;

Serial.println("A");

break;

case'B':

keycode1 = KEY_NEXT;

Serial.println("B");

break;

case 'C':

keycode1 = KEY_SELECT;

Serial.println("C");

break;

case 'D':

keycode1 = KEY_BACK;

Serial.println("D");

break;

}

if (keypressed != 'A' && keypressed != 'B' && keypressed !='C' && keypressed != 'D')

keycode1 = KEY_NONE;

}

if (keycode2 == keycode1)

keycode = keycode1;

else

keycode = KEY_NONE;

}

define MENU_ITEMS 4
const char *menu_strings[MENU_ITEMS] = {"Start", "Hello", "Let's Go", "End"};

uint8_t menu_current = 0;

uint8_t menu_redraw = 0;

uint8_t Last_key_code = KEY_NONE;

void drawmenu(void){

uint8_t i, h;

u8g_uint_t w, d;

u8g.setFont(u8g_font_6x13);

u8g.setFontRefHeightText();

u8g.setFontPosTop();

h = u8g.getFontAscent()-u8g.getFontDescent();

w = u8g.getWidth();

for( i = 0; i < MENU_ITEMS; i++ ) {

d = (w-u8g.getStrWidth(menu_strings[i]))/2;

u8g.setDefaultForegroundColor();

if ( i == menu_current ) {

u8g.drawBox(0, ih+1, w, h);

u8g.setDefaultBackgroundColor();

} u8g.drawStr(d, ih, menu_strings[i]);

} }

void updatemenu(void){

if (keycode != KEY_NONE && Last_key_code == keycode) {

return; } Last_key_code = keycode;

switch(keycode){

case KEY_NEXT:

menu_current ++;

if (menu_current >= MENU_ITEMS)

menu_current =0;

menu_redraw = 1;

break;

case KEY_PREV:

if (menu_current ==0)

menu_current = MENU_ITEMS;

menu_current --;

menu_redraw = 1;

break;

} }

void setup (){

Serial.begin(9600);

menu_redraw = 1;

}

void loop (){

keymode();

if (menu_redraw !=0) {

u8g.firstPage();

do{

drawmenu();

}while(u8g.nextPage());

menu_redraw = 0;

} updatemenu();

}
```

Comment: it is unclear how you want the code to work ... you need to provide clear description of expected behavior  ... your question is unanswerable until you do so

Comment: I just want to make a clear menu and to be able to scroll down without problems, 
after that i will move to the next part.

Comment: https://github.com/neu-rah/ArduinoMenu will handle IO for you